# Unable to send base 64 Image data to server with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, base64, http-status-code-400

I am trying to send Base64 Image data to the server with $http Post request, It is working for lower resolution images (upto 100KB) But not working for higher resolution images (trying for 6MB file).

Getting Error: 400 Bad Request.

```
    $http({url:ServerURL,method: "POST",
            params: {imageData:base64_imgData}
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.status);
    },function(response) {
       console.log(response.data);
       console.log(response.status);
    });
```

Please help how to overcome with this issue.

Comment: possibly a server side issue

Comment: Share more info about you server.

Comment: Sounds to me that your web server's max upload size configuration is limited to something below 6MB.

Comment: I am using Tomcat7 server, File size is limited to 100MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Jay, your answer helped me.

Issue resolved by using Jquery Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: ServerURL,
   data: { 
         imageData:base64_imgData
   },
   cache: false,
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   success: function (result) {
       console.log("Success");
   }
});
```

I think sending base 64 image data to server is not recommended for large size images, this is a very good way to run out of memory. better to use files and send the file.

Answer (score 0):

Break the base 64 into multiple parts (after your criteria to determine size, use your discretion to decide number parts) and do an update on the initially created object, if you wish to use the base 64 style of sending data. Else please refer to some angular modules for file upload below :

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-file-upload

If it was a JAVA Rest API, I would have straight away recommended multipart form data file upload mechanism. Please let me know if you want anything more.

Comment: Thanks so much Jay, I was looking for this as I am using JAVA Rest API. I will check with this & get back to you., Hope this will work :)

Comment: Sure. Welcome. If you need the code I will be happy to share with you. Hope this answer can resolve your problem.